# Could not find gem 'another-jekyll-plugin x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources

Tags: ruby, windows, jekyll, bundler

I am trying to use jekyll on windows however when I run

> bundle exec jekyll serve

I get an error saying

> Could not find gem 'rspec (~> 3.4) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem
>   sources listed in your Gemfile or in gems cached in vendor/cache. Run
>   `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Then when I run bundle install I get

> Could not find gem 'another-jekyll-plugin x64-mingw32' in any of the
>   gem sources listed in your Gemfile or in gems cached in vendor/cache.

here is the bundle env

### Environment

```
Bundler       2.0.2
  Platforms   ruby, x64-mingw32
Ruby          2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x64-mingw32]
  Full Path   D:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  Config Dir  C:/ProgramData
RubyGems      2.7.6.2
  Gem Home    D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  Gem Path    C:/Users/austi/.gem/ruby/2.5.0;D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  User Path   C:/Users/austi/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  Bin Dir     D:/Ruby25-x64/bin
Tools
  Git         2.22.0.windows.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2019-06-13
Git SHA           496bca538
Released Version  true
```

### Gemfile

#### Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in jekyll-admin.gemspec
gemspec

# Site dependencies
gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
gem 'rake', '12.3.1'
group :jekyll_plugins do
    gem "jekyll-gist"
    gem "jekyll-coffeescript"
    gem "jekyll-assets"
    gem "another-jekyll-plugin"
  end
```

#### Gemfile.lock

```
<No D:/anautics/jekyll-admin/Gemfile.lock found>
```

### Gemspecs

#### jekyll-admin.gemspec

```rb
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'jekyll-admin/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "jekyll-admin"
  spec.version       = JekyllAdmin::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Mert Kahyaoğlu", "GitHub Open Source"]
  spec.email         = ["mertkahyaoglu93@gmail.com", "opensource@github.com"]

  spec.summary       = %q{wp-admin for Jekyll, but better}
  spec.description   = %q{Jekyll::Admin is a drop in administrative framework for Jekyll sites.}
  spec.homepage      = "https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin"
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
  # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
  if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "https://rubygems.org"
  else
    raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
  end

  spec.files         = Dir.glob("lib/**/*").concat(%w(LICENSE README.md))
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_dependency "jekyll", "~> 3.3"
  spec.add_dependency "sinatra", "~> 1.4"
  spec.add_dependency "sinatra-contrib", "~> 1.4"
  spec.add_dependency "addressable", "~> 2.4"

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.7"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.4"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rubocop", "~> 0.57.2"
  spec.add_development_dependency "sinatra-cross_origin", "~> 0.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "gem-release", "~> 0.7"
end
```

Comment: What is `another-jekyll-plugin`? It [does not exist on RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=another-jekyll-plugin). Is it something you wrote, but forgot to upload? Is it uploaded to a different server, e.g. `gemfury` or some other private host? Is it a gem which is on your **local** machine, and you don't plan to upload it? Either way, that's what the error says: It does not exist on the one source that's listed in the `Gemfile`.

Comment: I followed the tutorial at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/installation/ @TomLord

Comment: Right.... Well perhaps one could blame the tutorial for being poorly written, but that's only been included as an **EXAMPLE**. `jekyll-gist`, `jekyll-coffeescript`, etc are real plugins, but `another-jekyll-plugin` is not. Perhaps the author of that guide should have done better to make it absolutely crystal clear to "not follow this guide word-for-word, since it includes a fake library name".

Comment: In fact, why not click the "Improve this page" [link](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/edit/master/docs/_docs/plugins/installation.md) and suggest an edit yourself, which you feel would have made it clearer to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```sh
gem install jekyll-sitemap
gem install jekyll-seo-tag
gem install jekyll-autoprefixer

gem install <any jekyll plugin name here>
```

and then

```sh
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

It will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

another-jekyll-plugin means that the plugin which you want use and put its name in place of that.. its not a plugin